# Always show the cancel button in a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I use a table view with a `UISearchDisplayController` in conjunction with a `UISearchBar`. The search bar automatically hides the cancel button when inappropriate, but I'm using the view controller in a modal state - so I would like to always show the cancel button and use it to pop the modal view controller when the search is cancelled.

Is there a way to force the cancel button to stay visible without creating a custom search bar?

Comment: What happens if you set by calling instance method setShowsCancelButton:animated:

Comment: Setting the button to visible in the delegate methods doesn't work, neither does subclassing `UISearchBar` and overriding all `showsCancelButton` methods.

Answer (score 3):

you should use the display delegate

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

Comment: Wow...Who feels dumb for just discovering `showsCancelButton`...? This guy >>

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{    
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a [solution](http://www.headcrap.de/bits/cool-or-fool-uisearchbar-always-display-cancel-button.html) after searching a lot.

It currently works for me. After adding in the code, I changed the class in Interface Builder to use the class instead of `UISearchBar`. I also have "Shows Cancel Button" enabled.

The code:

```
//NoAnimatingSearchBar.h
@interface NoAnimatingSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end

//NoAnimatingSearchBar.m
#import "NoAnimatingSearchBar.h"

@implementation NoAnimatingSearchBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) _destroyCancelButton {
    NSLog(@"_destroyCancelButton");
}

-(void)_setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    NSLog(@"_setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton");
}
@end
```

Comment: I know this thread is old, but it appears this solution uses private APIs, and will likely result in the app being rejected during app review.